# Copy .svg to clipboard with keyboard buttons or right click in a shiny app

Tags: r, svg, shiny, copy

I have the shiny app below in which I download .`svg` file. Instead of downloading it I want ideally to to be able to copy it to clipboard with Ctrl+C or even be able to right-click on the image and copy to clipboard.

```
library(shiny)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(tidyverse)
# probably don't need all of these:
library(DiagrammeRsvg)
library(rsvg)
library(V8)# only for svg export but also does not work
library(xml2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("save_svg","Save"),
  grVizOutput("grr",width = "100%",height = "90vh")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  reactives <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    reactives$graph <- render_graph(create_graph() %>%
                                      add_n_nodes(n = 2) %>%
                                      add_edge(
                                        from = 1,
                                        to = 2,
                                        edge_data = edge_data(
                                          value = 4.3)))
  })
  output$grr <-
    renderGrViz(reactives$graph
    )
  output$save_svg <- downloadHandler(
    
    filename = function() {
      "test.svg"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      reactives$graph %>%
        export_svg() %>%
        read_xml() %>%
        write_xml(file)
    }
  )
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Have you tried `rclipboard`? It doesn't work when you run the application locally but should work from your browser. [You can read more here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rclipboard/index.html). There's another option on Github. [You can read about that option here](https://github.com/deepanshu88/shinyCopy2clipboard).

Comment: these are for text I think

Comment: Erm, but SVG is XML, which is text.

Comment: I mean how can you replace input$copytext from https://github.com/sbihorel/rclipboard and combine it with my code?

Comment: so finally there is no solution to this?