# How to add controls in pan&zoom functionality in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, zooming, pan

I have used `panzoom` package in order to pan and zoom on my svg file in my shiny app. Is there a way to have controls like [this](https://github.com/bumbu/svg-pan-zoom)?

```
library(shiny)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/panzoom@9.4.0/dist/panzoom.min.js")
  ),

  grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh"),

  tags$script(
    HTML('panzoom($("#grr")[0])')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  reactives <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    reactives$graph <- render_graph(create_graph() %>%
                                      add_n_nodes(n = 2) %>%
                                      add_edge(
                                        from = 1,
                                        to = 2,
                                        edge_data = edge_data(
                                          value = 4.3)))
  })

  output$grr <- renderGrViz(reactives$graph)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The options are documented [here](https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom). What do you want to do?

Comment: something like https://bumbu.me/svg-pan-zoom/demo/inline.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way, but if you click too quickly on the +/- buttons, there's an undesirable effect.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  var element = document.getElementById("grr");
  var instance = panzoom(element);
  $("#zoomout").on("click", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 0.9);
  });
  $("#zoomin").on("click", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1.1);
  });
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/panzoom@9.4.0/dist/panzoom.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),

  grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh"),

  actionGroupButtons(
    inputIds = c("zoomout", "zoomin"),
    labels = list(icon("minus"), icon("plus")),
    status = "primary"
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  reactives <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    reactives$graph <- render_graph(
      create_graph() %>%
        add_n_nodes(n = 2) %>%
        add_edge(
          from = 1,
          to = 2,
          edge_data = edge_data(
            value = 4.3
          )
        )
      )
  })

  output$grr <- renderGrViz(reactives$graph)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## EDIT

Add this JavaScript to prevent the undesirable effect:

```
  $("#zoomout").on("dblclick", function(){
    return false;
  });
  $("#zoomin").on("dblclick", function(){
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: thanks maybe you could help with your expertise on shiny https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356501/copy-svg-to-clipboard-with-keyboard-buttons-or-right-click-in-a-shiny-app

Comment: how can I add a reset button as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397174/add-a-zoom-reset-button-in-svg-file-in-shiny-app

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but I love this solution! Question: I often have to move the map further to the right to make certain input clickable - it seems the svg covers other elements. Anyone to assign this to a z-index or place it in the background?