# Add a zoom reset button in svg file in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, zooming, pan

I have the `shiny` app below in which I want to add controls for pan and zoom like [here](https://bumbu.me/svg-pan-zoom/demo/inline.html) using the panzoom package. I have added `+/-` but what about a reset option? If you know any other package that can do it feel free to do it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  var element = document.getElementById("grr");
  var instance = panzoom(element);
  $("#zoomout").on("click", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 0.9);
  });
  $("#zoomin").on("click", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1.1);
  });
});
$("#zoomout").on("dblclick", function(){
    return false;
  });
  $("#zoomin").on("dblclick", function(){
    return false;
  });
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/panzoom@9.4.0/dist/panzoom.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  
  grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh"),
  
  actionGroupButtons(
    inputIds = c("zoomout", "zoomin"),
    labels = list(icon("minus"), icon("plus")),
    status = "primary"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  reactives <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    reactives$graph <- render_graph(
      create_graph() %>%
        add_n_nodes(n = 2) %>%
        add_edge(
          from = 1,
          to = 2,
          edge_data = edge_data(
            value = 4.3
          )
        )
    )
  })
  
  output$grr <- renderGrViz(reactives$graph)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  var element = document.getElementById("grr");
  var instance = panzoom(element);
  var z = 1;
  $("#zoomout").on("click", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 0.9);
    z *= 0.9;
  });
  $("#zoomin").on("click", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1.1);
    z *= 1.1;
  });
  $("#reset").on("click", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1/z);
    z = 1;
  });
  $("#zoomout").on("dblclick", function(){
    return false;
  });
  $("#zoomin").on("dblclick", function(){
    return false;
  });
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/panzoom@9.4.0/dist/panzoom.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  
  grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh"),
  
  actionGroupButtons(
    inputIds = c("zoomout", "zoomin", "reset"),
    labels = list(icon("minus"), icon("plus"), "Reset"),
    status = "primary"
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  reactives <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    reactives$graph <- render_graph(
      create_graph() %>%
        add_n_nodes(n = 2) %>%
        add_edge(
          from = 1,
          to = 2,
          edge_data = edge_data(
            value = 4.3
          )
        )
    )
  })
  
  output$grr <- renderGrViz(reactives$graph)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I got an issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70420503/zoom-and-reset-contollers-do-not-work-when-placed-in-uioutput-in-shiny-app