# Zoom and reset contollers do not work when placed in UiOutput in shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which I use js to add controls to zoom and reset on a `svg` file. It was working until the moment I put the output inside another UiOutput.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
var element = document.getElementById("grr");
var instance = panzoom(element);
var z = 1;
$("#zoomout").on("click", function(){
instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 0.9);
z *= 0.9;
});
$("#zoomin").on("click", function(){
instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1.1);
z *= 1.1;
});
$("#reset").on("click", function(){
instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1/z);
z = 1;
});
$("#zoomout").on("dblclick", function(){
return false;
});
$("#zoomin").on("dblclick", function(){
return false;
});
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/panzoom@9.4.0/dist/panzoom.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  
  uiOutput("main")
  #grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh"),

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$main <- renderUI({
    div(
      grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh"),
      
      actionGroupButtons(
        inputIds = c("zoomout", "zoomin", "reset"),
        labels = list(icon("minus"), icon("plus"), "Reset"),
        status = "primary"
      )
    )
    
  })
  output$grr <- renderGrViz(render_graph(
    create_graph() %>%
      add_n_nodes(n = 2) %>%
      add_edge(
        from = 1,
        to = 2,
        edge_data = edge_data(
          value = 4.3
        )
      )
  ))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the elements defined in the `renderUI` are not ready yet when the document is ready. A possible technique is to use an interval which will "screen" the document every 100ms, until it finds the element.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  var instance;
  var myinterval = setInterval(function(){
    var element = document.getElementById("grr");
    if(element !== null){
      clearInterval(myinterval);
      instance = panzoom(element);
    }
  }, 100);
  var z = 1;
  $("body").on("click", "#zoomout", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 0.9);
    z *= 0.9;
  });
  $("body").on("click", "#zoomin", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1.1);
    z *= 1.1;
  });
  $("body").on("click", "#reset", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1/z);
    z = 1;
  });
  $("body").on("dblclick", "#zoomout", function(){
    return false;
  });
  $("body").on("dblclick", "#zoomin", function(){
    return false;
  });
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/panzoom@9.4.0/dist/panzoom.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  
  uiOutput("main")
  #grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh"),
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$main <- renderUI({
    div(
      grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh"),
      
      actionGroupButtons(
        inputIds = c("zoomout", "zoomin", "reset"),
        labels = list(icon("minus"), icon("plus"), "Reset"),
        status = "primary"
      )
    )
    
  })
  output$grr <- renderGrViz(render_graph(
    create_graph() %>%
      add_n_nodes(n = 2) %>%
      add_edge(
        from = 1,
        to = 2,
        edge_data = edge_data(
          value = 4.3
        )
      )
  ))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: any idea why this bug happens? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70426286/reset-button-reset-svg-in-random-size-when-is-pressed-multiple-times

Comment: any idea about this shiny issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70654675/subset-based-on-number-of-rows-of-dataframe-displays-one-less-row-than-expected