# Reset button reset svg in random size when "-" is pressed multiple times

Tags: r, shiny, zooming

In the shiny app below I zoom and reset on a svg file. As you can see in the  [gif](https://upwork-usw2-prod-file-storage-wp2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/workplace/attachment/8552d1c06321517d7f0194dd3e9e81ce?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22EXHNlpvHWx.gif%22%3B%20filename%2A%3Dutf-8%27%27EXHNlpvHWx.gif&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEAkaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIH5IaA2CQ5d3nYgEHZVyDyhwJfG%2Bl9QrEEbrNSk3it20AiEAs8JucS9km8fRnlorffndwKDjXbU0ykdFV1suwF5ivCgq1gQI8v%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAAGgw3Mzk5MzkxNzM4MTkiDB2tERx7qN8GX0vbkyqqBA55%2F0X%2B5bIK%2Bn%2F2Ype8egEUbS1zTZBXgNC4Ho6ydqfCaPVSvplv%2FVrSp2C7KPY2DyOQhhQ%2F7Tz9XbxOeVTRTLIBPainKtd84WhfBQxapLCLfXYUvgYMJTwU%2BoYTi6riK0vpSD8uN5wP%2BNHL36275DUZvjTXWOpIPnjQ%2Fve2RBX4jTz8c2ibAimKPRem4nUC%2FLPsnSL8E2tYndVTN2CKYW2Hu3%2BQiuNwa8BRKDz4nbbGfeWioJ8vZfgpqsqWPAndjlNN%2B%2BGRvQ5IXBapDShJTuIkm8VscQ0jPOq5UtX8WDm9t%2B36fn%2BUmspFQ0V6qZeI9cMqJ7ylvLCZ4D8A%2B8oCfoPaf2jbAAC1WAg7buqRxnbUPggrM9x9Zt30keab8ig5N0U7EilQ4X6s%2FF%2F5NP5ulxAOj23xhaVRHThViNI52%2Bh6aQcPbhJPA69SoSFhHMGBcDmDf37tvURYec97%2BJKZHlzItx2Yftnub9lvmSocA52DEIpEmKi4Xb6IsHpfJetpWHd7%2Fg1Rj2IpWAgKMpmsDK%2BGLtSrZBYumPB%2BUEvsfuvLIG5NMBilq5eC99wXQAxXsgdBjzsMHFT5jD4B2yvXypiOq4KFnXqRLduNYXlTdqzxckMgPhN14kKj8N7R867s947h5XgaVEUCIJRgDqIcDhzmV310HaLD28GDrk1T6pz%2Fz4oVLy07ct7UHsBT7HbX%2BXuQ%2BvfSmCsIKS5r9fS0m%2BUzPoPVam965RRfMKLhgo4GOqcB2kCqO84iADTcecbZ3zkZ9HEws9wLorWEbV4jDtzXp%2FaZpI%2FL7rJBb7WgBdnpO4Z9ZFbp%2BB4J%2FLWAIydCZjt587DUsHN2F75O9uMFYPaBl2ZJ%2F8cDDPXno1jO2HrXM8ThIMFoUAMtfpJvmh4qehBOmA49tPvgPZh%2BN26tS6Quq8I%2FBUdOaBWP%2Bk1Lz%2Fh9dTftJwRi5%2BT1YUomMvN87IfxXT4ipZ6kNuk%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211220T182718Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=599&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA2YR6PYW5XQSZC3MG%2F20211220%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=58f8d39b1d8a2760dac3d6231deb49e36d1a4aba36d5f8d72b71696d2043807c) if you click the buttons quickly in succession, the script seems to lose track and resize randomly? In the gif, I click the `-` button repeatedly and then at the end press Reset.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  var instance;
  var myinterval = setInterval(function(){
    var element = document.getElementById("grr");
    if(element !== null){
      clearInterval(myinterval);
      instance = panzoom(element);
    }
  }, 100);
  var z = 1;
  $("body").on("click", "#zoomout", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 0.9);
    z *= 0.9;
  });
  $("body").on("click", "#zoomin", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1.1);
    z *= 1.1;
  });
  $("body").on("click", "#reset", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1/z);
    z = 1;
  });
  $("body").on("dblclick", "#zoomout", function(){
    return false;
  });
  $("body").on("dblclick", "#zoomin", function(){
    return false;
  });
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/panzoom@9.4.0/dist/panzoom.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  
  uiOutput("main")
  #grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh"),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$main <- renderUI({
    div(
      grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh"),
      
      actionGroupButtons(
        inputIds = c("zoomout", "zoomin", "reset"),
        labels = list(icon("minus"), icon("plus"), "Reset"),
        status = "primary"
      )
    )
    
  })
  output$grr <- renderGrViz(render_graph(
    create_graph() %>%
      add_n_nodes(n = 2) %>%
      add_edge(
        from = 1,
        to = 2,
        edge_data = edge_data(
          value = 4.3
        )
      )
  ))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: the link to your gif is not the right one

Comment: sorry cant add it.but can you reproduce the situation that Im describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar app with another **panzoom** library. It works better.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)

js <- '
  var element = document.getElementById("grr");
  var panzoom = Panzoom(element, {
    maxScale: 5
  });
  var z = 1;
  $("#zoomout").on("click", function(){
    z *= 0.9;
    panzoom.zoom(z, { animate: true });
  });
  $("#zoomin").on("click", function(){
    z *= 1.1;
    panzoom.zoom(z, { animate: true });
  });
  $("#reset").on("click", function(){
    z = 1;
    panzoom.reset();
  });
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/@panzoom/panzoom@4.4.3/dist/panzoom.min.js")
  ),

  uiOutput("main")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$main <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      div(
        grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh"),

        actionGroupButtons(
          inputIds = c("zoomout", "zoomin", "reset"),
          labels = list(icon("minus"), icon("plus"), "Reset"),
          status = "primary"
        )
      ),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    )

  })

  output$grr <- renderGrViz(render_graph(
    create_graph() %>%
      add_n_nodes(n = 2) %>%
      add_edge(
        from = 1,
        to = 2,
        edge_data = edge_data(
          value = 4.3
        )
      )
  ))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: yes indeed thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's the same strange bug I encountered the first time. A possible solution is to put the script in the renderUI:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(magrittr)

js <- '
  var element = document.getElementById("grr");
  instance = panzoom(element);
  var z = 1;
  $("#zoomout").on("click", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 0.9);
    z *= 0.9;
  });
  $("#zoomin").on("click", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1.1);
    z *= 1.1;
  });
  $("#reset").on("click", function(){
    instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1/z);
    z = 1;
  });
  $("#zoomout").on("dblclick", function(){
    return false;
  });
  $("#zoomin").on("dblclick", function(){
    return false;
  });
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/panzoom@9.4.0/dist/panzoom.min.js")
  ),
  
  uiOutput("main")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$main <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      div(
        grVizOutput("grr", width = "100%", height = "90vh"),
        
        actionGroupButtons(
          inputIds = c("zoomout", "zoomin", "reset"),
          labels = list(icon("minus"), icon("plus"), "Reset"),
          status = "primary"
        )
      ),
      tags$script(HTML(js))
    )
    
  })
  
  output$grr <- renderGrViz(render_graph(
    create_graph() %>%
      add_n_nodes(n = 2) %>%
      add_edge(
        from = 1,
        to = 2,
        edge_data = edge_data(
          value = 4.3
        )
      )
  ))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: tx but if you click + or - repeatedly & quickly (which users would likely
often do) then the reset button resets to the wrong size.